# Laravel problem with parameter in GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, guzzle

## Hello

When I use `GuzzleHttp\Client` is working fine but `form_params` not working but It was working with me in another project but this project no params working with me when I send it in `form_params`

**Guzzle Code working**

```
$http = new Client;

                        try {
                            $response = $http->post('https://smsmisr.com/api/webapi/?username='.$this->username.'&password='.$this->password.'&language=1&sender='.$this->sender.'&mobile=XXXX&message=Hello&DelayUntil='.Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());

                            // retrun json_decode((string)) $response->getBody(), true);
                            return $response->getBody();

                        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
                            if($e->getCode() === 400) {
                                return response()->json('Invalid Request.', $e->getCode());
                            } else if ($e->getCode() === 401) {
                                return response()->json('Your username and passowrd are incorrect', $e->getCode());
                            }
                            return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server', $e->getCode());
                        }
```

**Guzzle Code not working**
the code no sends any form_params yet.

```
$response = $http->post($this->link, [
    'headers' => [
        'User-Agent' => 'testing/1.0',
        'Accept'     => 'application/json',
        'X-Foo'      => ['Bar', 'Baz']
    ],
    'form_params' => [
        'username' => $this->username,
        'password' => $this->password,
        'sender' => $this->sender,
        'language' => 1,
        'mobile' => 'XXXXXXX',
        'message' => 'Hello guys',
        'DelayUntil' => Carbon::now()->toDateString()
    ]
]);
```

This problem in my Vuejs too when using Axios I should make
s

```
ubmitForm(context, data) {
            const params = {
                ...data
            }
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.post(`${data.post.apiURL}`, params)
                    .then(response => {
                        resolve(response)
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        reject(error)
                    })
            })
        },
```

I testing on PostMan.

Comment: Have you tried using `json` instead of `form_params`, as described [here](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#json)? Ran into this problem not too long ago when using `form_params`, it worked with `json`. Would also help if you could post the actual error you're getting (if any).

Comment: it's give me same error

Comment: ```'json' => [
                                    'username' => $this->username,
                                    'password' => $this->password,
                                    'sender' => $this->sender,
                                    'language' => 1,
                                    'mobile' => XXXXX,
                                    'message' => 'Hello guys',
                                    'DelayUntil' => Carbon::now()->toDateString()
                                ]```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: {"code":"8001"} its mean mobile is null Idk how but when sending mobile in URL it gives me username is null too

Comment: It's mean not params sending

Answer (score 1):

From the docs [here](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params)

`form_params` cannot be used with `json`:

> form_params cannot be used with the multipart option. You will need to use one or the other. Use form_params for application/x-www-form-urlencoded requests, and multipart for multipart/form-data requests.
>
> This option cannot be used with body, multipart, or json

Comment: what I can use then?

Answer (score 1):

Try this bro, change "form_params" to "json"

```
    $response = $http->post($this->link, [
'headers' => [
    'User-Agent' => 'testing/1.0',
    'Accept'     => 'application/json',
    'X-Foo'      => ['Bar', 'Baz']
],
'json' => [
    'username' => $this->username,
    'password' => $this->password,
    'sender' => $this->sender,
    'language' => 1,
    'mobile' => 'XXXXXXX',
    'message' => 'Hello guys',
    'DelayUntil' => Carbon::now()->toDateString()
] ]);
```